# Theming 'Material Design Components for Web' in Angular 2

Tags: angular, webpack, sass, angular-cli

I am trying to use MDC for Web. To start with I am first setting the theme. 
Followed this.

1. `npm install -g @angular/cli`
2. `ng new --style scss test-project`
3. `cd test-project`
4. `npm i material-components-web --save`
5. `npm i`
6. Open `styles.scss` and add the following

   ```
   $mdc-theme-primary: #002D72;
   $mdc-theme-accent: #f98710;
   $mdc-theme-background: #fff;

   @import "../node_modules/material-components-web/material-components-web";
   //@import "~material-components-web/material-components-web";
   ```

This gives error :

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./~/postcss-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/styles.scss
Module build failed: 
@import "@material/animation/mdc-animation";
^
      File to import not found or unreadable: @material/animation/mdc-animation.
```

I understand I get this error as in MDC for Web all the paths set directly (not relative). 
They have imports like this :

```
@import "@material/animation/mdc-animation";
```

For us to work , it should be

```
@import "~@material/animation/mdc-animation";
```

Need help how to fix this. May be I need to eject angular-cli and configure its webpack configuration.

Answer (score 0):

### Without @angular/cli

I consider this as workaround. Not exactly solution for the above issue.

If you wish to use readily available project. I uploaded my working solution here :

> Seed at https://github.com/pvamshi/MDC-web-starter

I could get it working without angular-cli . Here is what I did .

I have `sass-loader` already included in the webpack configuration. Just added these in `sass-loader` options.

```
includePaths: [
     path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules"),
     path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/@material/**/*")
]
```

In my main style.scss added this :

```
$mdc-theme-primary: #002D72;
$mdc-theme-accent: #f98710;
$mdc-theme-background: #fff;

@import "~@material/theme/mdc-theme.scss";
```

It would be great for everyone if someone can work this with `@angular/cli`